# Keep system clock synchronized to hardware clock

Tags: clock, ntpd

The situation:

- We have some Linux VMs running compute jobs.
- The VMs do not have Internet access (including NTP).
- The hypervisor does know the correct time.
- The hypervisor's time is exposed to the VM via its hardware clock.
- The hypervisor seems to be QEMU/KVM-based. We do not control the hypervisor (it is a cloud VPS offering).

The problem:

- The VMs' system clock drifts away from the correct time / hardware clock.

The question:

- Is it possible to keep the system clock synchronized to the hardware clock at all times?
- Alternatively, is it possible to tell e.g. ntpd to account for system clock drift, using the hardware clock as reference?

What I tried:

- A `0 * * * * hwclock --hctosys` cronjob, however, the drift is significant enough that even hourly synchronization is insufficient, and increasing the cronjob frequency seems like a workaround at this point.

Comment: Can the host machine serve the clock via NTP to the VMs?  My old cluster was configured to have three machines which accessed the network and established a local authoritative time, and all the other nodes in the cluster only accessed these three.  Wiht a host and VMs you can forget the three cooperating and just have the one master.

Comment: Depending on the VM subsystem you should be able to lock the VM clocks to the hypervisor. Please can you [edit] your question to identify the virtualisation solution you're using

Comment: @Martin No, I suppose we could adjust infrastructure to allow NTP but I was hoping for a local-only solution which wouldn't involve that. Unfortunately we don't control the hypervisor so it would mean allowing network access just for this in some form or another.

Comment: @roaima Done. And thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

[I'm working from memory here so I will try to check this later.]

QEMU/KVM virtual machines can synchronise their clock to the host through the virtualisation layer.

Here's how you confirm that your guest is using the host:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
kvm-clock
```

If it doesn't return that value `kvm-clock` you need to load the paravirtualisation clock module in your client, part of the `virtio` kernel modules.

Do not run `ntpd` (or any other external synchronisation) if your VM is synchronising with the host.

Comment: I am also getting the value `kvm-clock` there. However, the system and hardware clocks still do drift apart.

Comment: I'll look on our systems